# A problem with accessing a variable that comes from a third-party script in next js

Tags: next.js

I work with next.js on a project that needs to load a third-party script. for this I use:
`import Script from 'next/script';`, directly in my layout component.
I will also mention that I use:
`strategy="beforeInteractive"`, So:
`<Script src="https://example.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />`.

Inside a component on the page of the layout, I declare a variable that comes from the script I'm loading:
`declare var MyIncomingVariable: any;`.

Inside useEffect i check:
`if (!MyIncomingVariable) {...}`.

My problem is that when I navigate to this page using a nextjs link, I get an error:
`ReferenceError: MyIncomingVariable is undefined`.
Only when I refresh the page, the page comes up normally.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using pages or app router?

Comment: I am using app router

Comment: No.  Currently I have to load the script in the root page.